# how to use Dome parser in android

Tags: java, android

http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetISD this is web service i want to parse and get code suppose if pass india then it should return.

```
public String CountryName(String Country)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet htpget=new HttpGet("http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetISD");

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htpget);
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
            }
        return code;

    }
```

I am getting Response code 200 But i am Unable to do Dom Parsing please help how i will implemnt how i will get code from DOm Parsing .

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: .
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

This Error is coming

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Youre only using the .getStatusLine() - isnt it just response.toString()?

Comment: what i have to write please help

Comment: i am new in XML parsing please help

Comment: Im not going to write it for you. Maybe you should read a tutorial or two: 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [ksoap2](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html). The code to parse response looks like this:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
parseResponse(is, envelope);
```

and the response will be in the `envelope.bodyIn property` - it is very similar to json objects

```
private static void parseResponse(InputStream is, SoapEnvelope envelope)
          throws Throwable {
        try {
          XmlPullParser xp = new KXmlParser();
          xp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);                          

          xp.setInput(is, "UTF-8");

          envelope.parse(xp);
        } catch (Throwable e) {           
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error reading/parsing SOAP response", e);
            throw e;
        }
      }
```

Comment: can u please make method so that i can pass country name and it should response code  like if input (india ) then it return 91

Comment: I'm giving you directions how to write it, nobody here will provide you a complete solution.

Comment: I am new Just asking coz i am trying explore when Input country then corresponding ISD code

Comment: why don't you try it by yourself then? You can't rely only on stackoverflow and other forums, asking people to do it for you.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: .
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()  eRROR IS COMING

Comment: YAAR AM TRY eXPLORE IT bUT I AM UNABLE TO THIS SO AM ASKING EVEN I SERCH FROM gOOGLE ALSO BUT STILL FACING pROBLEM

Comment: probably your request is wrong. Read some tutorials on how to use such webservices in android. I don't have the time to guide somebody step by step

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following URL to use simple http request:

"http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetISD?CountryName="+yourCountryName

It gives XML response directly.

Comment: I need to display Country ISd Code if we call this web service Like we select india then it should display +91 please write method yaar am Stucking please help